# StreamSocket on WinRT doesn't receive all data

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, windows-runtime, datareader

I've a server running MPD (music player daemon) which communicates via sockets. Now I'm trying to implement the MPD protocol in a Windows store app. Basically I send a command and receive a list which has as the last line "OK". As long as the receving list is smaller than the receive buffer everything is ok. But if I need to load data which is bigger than the buffer the wired stuff starts.

When calling the `SendCommand` the first time I receive only part of the data, the rest is received when calling `SendCommand` a second time. When called once more I receive all data as expected. When doing this in a WPF program on the same machine everything is fine.

This is my code:

```
    public async Task<string> SendCommand(MpdProtocol.MpdCommand command)
    {
        DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(streamSocket.OutputStream);
        string res = string.Empty;

        writer.WriteString(command.ToString());
        await writer.StoreAsync();
        res = await ReadResponse();

        writer.DetachBuffer();
        writer.DetachStream();
        return res;
    }

    private async Task<string> ReadResponse()
    {
        DataReader reader = new DataReader(streamSocket.InputStream);
        reader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

        const uint MAX_BUFFER = 8 * 1024;
        uint returnBuffer = 0;
        do
        {
            returnBuffer = await reader.LoadAsync(MAX_BUFFER);
            response.Append(reader.ReadString(reader.UnconsumedBufferLength));

        } while (returnBuffer >= MAX_BUFFER);

        reader.DetachBuffer();
        reader.DetachStream();

        return response.ToString();
    }
```

I've played around with the `ReadResponse` method but nothing worked.

Can someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: I've tried different ways to read the data from the stream and nothing worked. The problem is that the 'DataReader' stops reading but there is still data to receive. And why does it work when calling 'SendCommand' a third time?

Comment: I see two obvious bugs in your code: you aren't calling `writer.FlushAsync()` after writing and before detaching the writer, and you are assuming that a single call to `LoadAsync()` will always fill the buffer unless there is no more data to be read. Without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, it would be impossible to say for sure what you need to do to fix the code. But I would start there.

Comment: (I'm also suspicious of the temporary use of the reader and writer...I would think it would be better to just create those once per connection and continue to use them until done with the connection. But I'm less familiar with the newer Windows Runtime I/O model and maybe your code is otherwise completely fine in that respect. I can't say for sure).

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I've found a solution to get the communication working: reading the stream byte by byte with `reader.ReadByte()` and check each received line (they are separated by `"\n"`) for being "OK".

The problem is `reader.ReadString`. This methond is good when you know how long the string is you'll try to receive. In my case I have no idea about the size of the string. All I know is that the last line will be an "OK" string.

My error was to belive  - as Peter mentioned - that as long as there is data to retrive the recive buffer will be filled completely and only the last call to `reader.ReadString` will be smaller than the max buffer size. I've also tried to rewrite the `ReadResponse` function in different ways but nothing worked for `reader.ReadString`.